# How do I create an Editor Add-In?

Tags: joomla-3.x, development, plugin, editor

I've searched around, but I can't find how to do this. I'd like to add an extension to the wysiwig editor in Joomla. I'm writing a calendar plugin, and I'd like to have a dialog that would help the user construct the short code to insert into the article/page/module content.

What I do in another CMS is hook the editor so when they click on my button, a dialog appears that helps them select which short code, and set the various options. Then, when they click on OK, I insert the shortcode into the content. If anyone could point me to a web page or article on how to do this, I would be really appreciative.

Comment: Just as a recommendation, you could try looking at another editors button plugin code to give you a start. JCE has several editor plugins that it uses that may give you some hints. Or for that matter maybe even the default readmore button logic could help you.

Comment: @George did the answer below solve your question?  All questions should progress to a system-recognized resolution.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the Editor there are several ways to extend the editor in Joomla — I'm going to assume you're talking about `editors-xtd` plugins. These are the buttons found below the main editor area.

There is a shortage of documentatoin on creating them so, as suggested, the best bet will be to look at existing editor extensions — I would start with the standard ones installed by default with Joomla. You can find the source code for them in the `/plugins/editors-xtd/` directory of your Joomla installation.

You can find currently available ones listed on the [Joomla Extension Directory here](http://extensions.joomla.org/tags/editor-buttons).

The `editor-xtd` plugins are like standard plugins so start with the [Plugin Developer Overview article](https://docs.joomla.org/Plugin_Developer_Overview) on [Joomla Docs](https://docs.joomla.org/).

The main things to remember are:

1. the plugin group is defined in the plugins XML file as `group="editors-xtd"`
2. the event triggered to display your custom button is `onDisplay()`

As it sounds the `onDisplay()` method is where you return the do all the prep for the button (like assembling the HTML of the button). The `onDisplay()` method should end with you return that html...

```
return $html;
```

Obviously in that `$html` you can specify Javascript events to be triggered by clicking on the button.

To load the Javascript into the page you should use Joomla's standard approaches in your plugins PHP file:

```
// Get the current document
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();

// Build your Javascript
$js = '...'

// Add it to the document as script block
$doc->addScriptDeclaration($js);

// Or if you have a lot of JS, it's probably best in it's own file…
$jsFile = '/path/to/js/file.js';

// Add the link to the doc's head…
$doc->addScript($jsFile);
```

There are other methods Joomla provides to get and set the content of the editor, save it and to get the name of a method to insert text at the current cursor position in the editor.